# How do you make a modal box appear directly underneath the link that was clicked to open it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a page of a website. This particular page has a button link. Once clicked, a modal box appears in the middle of the screen. It is sized just the way I want it, designed visually as I need it, however I want it to physically display below the link it was clicked from. Meaning, the top of the modal should be touching the bottom of the button link.

I tried styling it in CSS to fit my requirements, as well as asking ChatGPT for varying help with getting my jQuery code to do this. My CSS is:

```
.modal{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.modal-window{
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2rem;
    border-top: 2px solid #cecece;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1rem rgba(206, 206, 206, .5);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 4rem)
}
```

And here is my jQuery code. It includes the code for my button, which on click opens the modal. I got this from ChatGPT, but it didnt at all help or do as expected, so I am not sure Chat understands what I am asking:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ModalBtn').on('click', function() {
      var button = $(this);
      var modal = $('#modalClicked');
  
      modal.css({
        top: button.offset().top + button.outerHeight(),
        left: button.offset().left
      });
  
      modal.show();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where is your html code? If the modal is triggered only at one place you can leave the html tag of the modal next to the button that triggers it and then use `position: relative` on both.

Comment: Why has this been tagged with `handlebars.js` and `less`?

Comment: I am using handlebars with my HTML code, and CSS less. apologies.

Comment: And what is the output you have, and how it differs from what you want?